# importing an XML document

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, load

What I'm working on is a navigation bar populated by an XML document.

I'm working from an existing navigation bar while I learn, and the existing bar has a menu, and when clicked each button has a sub menu.

I'm trying to remove the submenu so that when you click the navigation bar button, you go to the address defined in the XML.

So far I've got everything working so that there is no sub menu drop down, and when you click a button, you are taken to a URL defined in the actual flash AS file.

I can't seem to get the AS file to call on the XML file to the get a URL from it though.

How do I tell the AS file to call a variable from the XML document?

I know I have the correct Node path because it works in a second AS file.

Comment: What navigation bar are you using? Is it an openly availble flash navigation? How does your xml look like? You should look into the actionscript reference, or tutorials like this: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/xml/

Comment: I also retagged your question, tags like [actionscript] or [flash] are important for others to find your question. [xml] is pretty generic, so is [load]

Comment: I'm using the exercise materials provided with a book called 'learning actionscript 3' found at www.learningactionscript3.com (I have the book). Typically, their website is down right now.

My XML is setup as 
<nav>
    
<buttons spacing="2">
        
<button label="3col">
            
<project label="button1" path="http://www.google.com">
            
</project>

The button label gives a button its name, the project label gives a submenu its name, and the project path is the URL I want to have the button go to.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data is done with `flash.net::URLLoader`. Fetch the loaded data on `Event.COMPLETE` (load operations are asynchronous), and convert it to XML using the top level XML function.

XML traversal is most easily done using [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML).